# How to access ArrayList in another class

Tags: java, arraylist, import

I have this code currently but it wont let me run it as there is an error, I know it is something to do with how I have imported the Library class however I do not know the appropriate way to fix this. I am trying to import the ArrayList to use when loading a save file. I want this ArrayList to be updated from that in the text file.

Here is my code:

```
package library;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Manual {

    String serial;
    String title;
    String author;
    String publicationYear;
    String status;
    String borrower;
    String borrowDate;
    String returnDate;  

Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); 

final String displayManual(){

    String ManualInfo ="\nSerial Number: ........... "+serial+ 
                    "\nTitle: ................... "+title+
                    "\nAuthor: .................. "+author+
                    "\nPublication Year: ........ "+publicationYear+
                    "\nStatus: .................. "+status+
                    "\nBorrower: ................ "+borrower+
                    "\nDate Borrowed: ........... "+borrowDate+
                    "\nReturn date: ............. "+returnDate+
                    "\n";
    return ManualInfo;  
}   

final void createManual(){

    serial = Console.readString(Messages.enterSerialMessage, Messages.tooShortMessage, 3);
    title = Console.readString(Messages.enterTitleMessage, Messages.tooShortMessage, 2);
    author = Console.readString(Messages.enterAuthorMessage, Messages.tooShortMessage, 3);
    publicationYear = Console.readString(Messages.enterPublicationYearMessage, Messages.tooShortMessage, 4);

    borrower = "N/A";
    borrowDate = "N/A";
    returnDate = "N/A";

    status = "Available";
}   
...

            if(Menu.menuChoice == 7){
                boolean loadYesNo = Console.readYesNo("\n\nThe manualKeeper app is able to load and display any 'Library.txt' files \nfound in your home folder directory.\n\nWould you like to load and display library? (Y/N):\n");
                String fileName = "Library.txt";
                String line;
                if(loadYesNo==true){
                try {
                    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (fileName));
                    if (!input.ready()) {
                        throw new IOException();
                    }
                    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                        Library.ManualList.add(line);
                    }
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }

                Menu.displayMenu();

                } else if(loadYesNo==false){
                    System.out.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("\n                             Library not loaded!\n");
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                    Menu.displayMenu();
                }
            }

...

            if(Menu.menuChoice == 0){
                if(Menu.menuChoice == 0){
                    if(Library.ManualList.size() > 0){
                        boolean saveYesNo = Console.readYesNo("\nThe manualKeeper app is able to save your current library to a '.txt' \nfile in your home folder directory (C:\\Users\\ 'YOUR NAME').\n\nWould you like to save the current library? (Y/N):\n");
                        File fileName = new File ("Library.txt");
                        if(saveYesNo==true){
                            try {
                                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
                                Writer output = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                                for (int i = 0; i < Library.ManualList.size(); i++){
                                    output.write(Library.ManualList.get(i).displayManual() + "\n");
                                }
                                output.close();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I cannot create that file!");
                                }
                        }
                            else if(saveYesNo==false){
                                System.out.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                                System.out.println("\n                              Library not saved!\n");
                                System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                                break exit;
                        }
                        Menu.displayMenu();
                    }else if(Library.ManualList.isEmpty()){ 
                        Menu.displayMenu();
                    }
                }
            }               

        }
    System.out.println("\n              ~   You have exited the manualKeeper app!   ~                  ");
    System.out.println("\n                  Developed by Oscar Moore - 2014 - UWL\n");
    System.out.println("\n                                   <3\n");

}
}
```

Here is my library class if needed:

```
package library;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Library {  

public static int ManualChoice;

static String returnManualTitle;

static String status1 = "Available";

static String status2 = "Borrowed"; 

public static ArrayList<Manual> ManualList = new ArrayList<Manual>();
static ArrayList<Manual> borrowedManuals = new ArrayList<Manual>();

static void addManual(){
    Manual newManual = new Manual(); 
    newManual.createManual();
    ManualList.add(newManual);
    System.out.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("\n                          Manual added to library!\n");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
}

static void displayManualList(){
    if (ManualList.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(Messages.empltyLibraryMessage + Messages.tryAgainMessage);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");
        Menu.menuChoice = 8;

    } else {    
        System.out.printf("\n\nHere are the Manual/s currently stored in the library:\n\n\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < ManualList.size(); i++){
            System.out.printf("-------------------- Index Number: %s --------------------\n",i);
            System.out.println(ManualList.get(i).displayManual());  
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------\n");
            }
        }
    }

static void displayBorrowedManuals(){
    if (ManualList.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(Messages.empltyLibraryMessage + Messages.tryAgainMessage);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");
        Menu.menuChoice = 8;

    } else {                    
        for (int i = 0; i < borrowedManuals.size(); i++){
            System.out.printf("-------------------- Index Number: %s --------------------\n",i);
            System.out.println(borrowedManuals.get(i).displayManual()); 
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
        }
    }
}

public static void borrowManual(){

    displayManualList();
    ManualChoice = (Console.readInteger(Messages.enterManualIndexMessage, Messages.ManualIndexNotInListMessage, 0, Library.ManualList.size() - 1));

    borrowLoop:
    while(Menu.menuChoice == 3){

        if ((ManualList.get(ManualChoice).status.equalsIgnoreCase(status1)) && (ManualList.size() >= ManualChoice)){
            ManualList.get(ManualChoice).status = "Borrowed";
            ManualList.get(ManualChoice).borrower = User.userName;
            ManualList.get(ManualChoice).borrowDate = "Today.";
            ManualList.get(ManualChoice).returnDate = "In two weeks.";
            borrowedManuals.add(ManualList.get(ManualChoice));
            System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("\n                             Manual borrowed!\n");
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            break borrowLoop;

        }else if(ManualList.get(ManualChoice).status.equalsIgnoreCase(status2) && ManualList.size() >= ManualChoice){
            System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("\n            "
                    + " The Manual you wish to borrow is already on loan.");
            System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            break borrowLoop;

        }else if(ManualChoice > ManualList.size()-1){
            System.out.println(Messages.noSuchManualMessage);
            break borrowLoop;
        }
    if(ManualList.size() > 1){
        displayManualList();
    }
    else if(ManualList.size() == 1){
        ManualList.get(ManualChoice).status = "Borrowed";
        ManualList.get(ManualChoice).borrower = User.userName;
        ManualList.get(ManualChoice).borrowDate = "Today.";
        ManualList.get(ManualChoice).returnDate = "In two weeks.";
        borrowedManuals.add(ManualList.get(ManualChoice));
        System.out.printf("\n\n %s\n\n", ManualList.get(ManualChoice).displayManual());
        System.out.println("Please return the Manual within two weeks!\n");
        displayManualList();
        }
    }
    Menu.displayMenu();
}

static void returnManual(){
    System.out.printf("\n\nHere are the Manual/s currently out on loan:\n\n");

    if(borrowedManuals.size() > 0){
    for (int i = 0; i < borrowedManuals.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(borrowedManuals.get(i).displayManual());
        returnManualTitle = Console.readString(Messages.enterManualSerial, Messages.tooShortMessage, 3);
    }

    int x = 0;
    boolean serialExistance = false;
    while (x < ManualList.size()){

        if (ManualList.get(x).serial.equalsIgnoreCase(returnManualTitle)){

            ManualList.get(x).status = "Available";
            ManualList.get(x).borrower = "N/A";
            ManualList.get(x).borrowDate = "N/A";
            ManualList.get(x).returnDate = "N/A";

            int p = 0;
                while (p < borrowedManuals.size()) {
                    Manual borrowed = borrowedManuals.get(p);
                    if (borrowed.serial.equalsIgnoreCase(returnManualTitle)) {
                        borrowedManuals.remove(p);
                        break;
                    }
                    p++;
                }               
            System.out.println(Messages.successReturnMessage);
            serialExistance = true;

            break;
        }
        x = x+1;
    }
    if(serialExistance == false){
        boolean repeatReturnManual = Console.readYesNo("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------" + "\n\nThe Manual with the serial "+"\""+returnManualTitle +"\""+ " wasn't found!"
                                                        +"\n\nDo you want to try again? (Y/N):\n");
        System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        if(repeatReturnManual){
            returnManual();
        }
    }else if(serialExistance){
        Menu.menuChoice = 8;
    }               
}

public static void removeManual(){

    if(ManualList.size() >0){
        displayManualList();
        ManualChoice = Console.readInteger(Messages.enterRemoveManualIndex ,Messages.ManualIndexNotInListMessage, 0, ManualList.size());        
        int p = 0;
        while (p < borrowedManuals.size()){

            if (borrowedManuals.get(p).title.equalsIgnoreCase(returnManualTitle)){

                borrowedManuals.remove(p);
            }
        }
        ManualList.remove(ManualChoice);
        System.out.print(Messages.successRemovedManualMessages);
        Menu.menuChoice = 8;
    }               
}

static void emptyLibrary(){
    System.out.println("\n                                 WARNING!");
    System.out.println("\n           You have chosen to delete all Manuals in the library.\n"); 
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    boolean emptyLibraryChoice = Console.readYesNo("\nAre you sure you wish to destroy the library? (Y/N): \n");
    System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    if(emptyLibraryChoice){
        Library.ManualList.clear();
        System.out.println(Messages.successEmptyLibraryMesssage);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        Menu.menuChoice = 8;
        }

}

}
```

The error is on the "Library.ManualList..." line. I am new to Java so can anyone help me get this working? :(

Comment: What is the exact error message? What is the type of Library.ManualList?

Comment: @David "
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 ManualList cannot be resolved" and an array. I have updated my code with my library class

Comment: They are not in the same package, so the default visibility (package visibility) is not sufficient. You must write `public static ArrayList<Manual> ManualList;` in class Library.

Comment: @David I added this to the library class however there is still an error on the same line :(

Comment: Please update the above code accordingly so we can follow your changes.

Comment: Can you please show the headers (package and imports) of the upper class?

Comment: Usually, when you get that error, it's something to do with the way you've compiled it, or the way you're running it.  The code itself is probably fine.  Have you actually compiled the `Library` class into a file called `Library.class`?  You can't run `Manual.class` without it.

Answer (score 0):

I do know know what the method signature looks like for this code segment, or what the `Library` class looks like, however I believe that the problem might lie in the declaration of the `ManualList`in the `Library` class.  `ManualList` should be both `public` and `static`, and that should give you the ability to access it in another class

Edit: 
I found in this line: `Library.ManualList.add(line);` you are adding a string to an array that holds a custom type.  Otherwise, compiling the code myself I found no problems.  This of course is assuming that the classes are in the same package, and I had to comment out alot of the code that I didn't have ( such as all the `Menu` references).  But it compiled for me.  I did  not run it

Edit2: Something i just thought of, the `final` modifier might cause some problems? But it worked for me when I tested it

Comment: unless it is absolutely necessary, does there need to be a separate 'library' package? It could simply be another class that is alongside of the menu operations

Comment: Do you mean the library text file that is created?

Comment: At the top of your 'Library' class, you have this code: 'package library;' and in your menu operations, is it also in 'package library;' or is it in a different package?

Comment: it is the same as the library class

Comment: Ok that is good. Then what did you mean when you said that you imported the the 'Library' class in the description/question?

Comment: Im not sure, I really dont know what is causing the issue im having right now so :(

Comment: Well that clears up that potential problem.  I think I may have a solution for you.  I will edit and put it in my original comment

Comment: is there any way I can send you my class files to get a better look at the issue? :( Ive been working all day on this

Comment: Sure. Are they on git? or you can send them to my email: rwendesy@gmail.com